# How to save/restore a bootstrap 5 offcanvas show/hide state?

Tags: save, state

I'm making a PHP toolbox script out of a Bootstrap 5 offcanvas. The Tookbox (offcanvas) is hidden by default. The User can show it or hide it when he wants by clicking a button. I'd like to save the shown/hidden state of the offcanvas to display it the next time the user will access to the page. For example if he left the script with the offcanvas shown, i'd like that the offcanvas automatically shows when the user comes back on the script... Can you help me ?

Did not tried anything interesting since I have no idea how to archieve this

Comment: You should save the state in a variable and when the user visits the page the next time, you should call the saved state from the variable.

Comment: Yes this is the way I'm forwarding to do it but I dont' know how to save / restore the state in javascript, Do i have to use a cookie to save the state ? And how to use it to tell bootstrap to restore it ?

Comment: Do something like this:                                                                                    
        `const offcanvasState = localStorage.getItem('toolboxOffcanvasState');\

        // Show/hide the offcanvas based on the saved state
        if (offcanvasState === 'shown') {
            document.getElementById('toolboxOffcanvas').classList.add('show');
        } else {
            document.getElementById('toolboxOffcanvas').classList.remove('show');`

Comment: Works great. Here is the full code : 
var offCanvasTools = document.getElementById('offCanvasTools');

offCanvasTools.addEventListener('hidden.bs.offcanvas', function () {
  sessionStorage.setItem('toolbox', 'off');
});
offCanvasTools.addEventListener('shown.bs.offcanvas', function () {
  sessionStorage.setItem('toolbox', 'on');
});

window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  if (sessionStorage.getItem('toolbox') == 'on') {
    offCanvasTools.classList.add('show');
  };
});